# Referencing libraries from other solution

Tags: dot42

I have custom library that is located in a separate solution. When I reference that library in a new solution everything works fine, except when I try to build it. I get the error:

**Error 1401    Failed to load assembly Utilities, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**

**Error 1402    Failed to resolve assembly: 'Utilities, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'**

Anyone had similar problems?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
Since Dot42 does not have Tuple class I created my own Tuple in my library and used the same namespace (System). Looks like there's a problem System.* namespaces are used. I wanted to use the same namespace to avoid defines in using clauses.

Once I changed namespace it started working :)